# Memcached expires at 300 seconds no matter what

Tags: php, memcached

My Memcached instance expires at 300 seconds. If I set it to something smaller than 300 seconds it works properly. However, if I set it for anything over 300 seconds it doesn't matter, it will always expire at 300 seconds.

I am using php and here is my code...

```
$memcache = new Memcached();
$memcache->addServer("localhost", 11211);

$cacheData = $memcache->get($key);

if(!$cacheData){
  $cacheData = database results;
  $memcache->set($key, $cacheData, 600);
}

return $cacheData;
```

I am just getting started with this project so I only have 1 api db call being stored. Is there some reason in my settings this might be happening, somewhere in the php.ini file?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

So many of my questions end up being issues with the server configuration and not the code.

I contacted my server admin for the tenth time today and begged him to check the logs to figure it out.

Turns out, they have a cPanel monitoring system in place and it was seeing that the memcached server was being run by user 'nobody' so it was shutting it down every 3 minutes. Then, my script would start it up again and the cycle would continue.

The admin had to name the memcached server user anything, like 'memcache', and then when the monitoring system checked the next time it saw a name it knew and thus didn't shut down the memcache server.

Was not sure whether to delete this question or answer it. Anyway, that's that!